# MySQL - Combine rows with different where statements

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two MySQL Querys i would like to combine.

```
SELECT DEVICE as Room, VALUE as Temperature FROM `current` WHERE `READING` LIKE 'temperature'
SELECT DEVICE as Room, VALUE as Humidity    FROM `current` WHERE `READING` LIKE 'humidity'
```

My Data Table looks like this:

| DEVICE | VALUE | READING |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arbeitszimmer | 52 | humidity |
| Arbeitszimmer | 22 | temperature |
| Aussen | 88 | humidity |
| Aussen | 1.8 | temperature |

The desired result should be:

| Room | Temperature | Humidity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Arbeitszimmer | 22 | 52 |
| Aussen | 1.8 | 88 |

I am struggeling with the SQL Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple self join should work

```
SELECT c1.DEVICE as Room, c1.VALUE as Temperature, c2.VALUE as Humidity  
FROM `current` c1 
    join `current` c2 on c1.device = c2.device 
        and c1.`READING` = 'temperature'
        and c2.`READING` = 'humidity'
```

BTW there is no need to use `like`

Answer (score 0):

if you have only two classs of values you could use a join with the same table

```
select a.device, a.value temp, b.value humidity
from current a  
inner join current a.device = b.device 
    and a.reading = 'temperature'
        and b.reading = 'humidity'
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of conditional aggregation to pivot the READING metrics.

```
SELECT `DEVICE` as Room
, MAX(CASE WHEN `READING` = 'temperature' THEN `VALUE` END) as Temperature
, MAX(CASE WHEN `READING` = 'humidity' THEN `VALUE` END) as Humidity
FROM `current` 
WHERE `READING` IN ('temperature', 'humidity') 
GROUP BY `DEVICE`
ORDER BY `DEVICE`
```